# Error al instalar composer en proyecto Symfony 2.8

Tags: php, symfony2, composer

¿Cómo instalar composer en un proyecto symfony 2.8 con php 5.6?
he aquí mi `composer.json`.

```
{
"name": "SIIG/eTAB",
"description": "SIIG/eTAB",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",

    "symfony/symfony": "2.6.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "v2.4.4",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "v1.2.0",
    "twig/extensions": "v1.0.1",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*@stable",
    "kriswallsmith/assetic": "1.1.x@stable",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "v2.3.7",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "v2.6.1",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "v2.3.4",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "v2.3.4",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "v2.3.5",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "v2.1.0",

    "doctrine/data-fixtures": "v1.0.0",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "v2.2.0",

    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle":"dev-master",

    "sonata-project/cache": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/cache-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/datagrid-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/core-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/block-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "dev-master",


    "simplethings/entity-audit-bundle": "v0.6",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "v1.3.3",
    "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "v1.5.3"
```

y me lanza el siguiente error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Debes eliminar el archivo composer.lock que tienes e instalar de nuevo el composer.phar

Comment: php5.6 es el requerimiento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Composer se puede instalar de la siguiente manera:

```
  curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Luego en la raiz de tu proyecto:

```
composer install
```

Answer (score 1):

El error en sí es bastante aclaratorio, estás intentando instalar la versión 2.3.2 de twig que requiere tener php7 o superior pero tu versión de php es la 5.6.30. En este punto tienes dos opciones:

- Actualiza la versión de php a una más reciente. Php7, PHP7.1 y PHP7.2 suponen un gran salto en rendimiento con respecto a php5.6
- Instala una versión de twig que soporte php5.6, [la más reciente es la v1.35.0](https://packagist.org/packages/twig/twig#v1.35.0), añadiendo: `"twig/twig" : "^1.35"`

Borrar el archivo de `composer.lock` es una muy mala idea. Tanto el `composer.json` como `composer.lock` son archivos que debería estar guardados en tu repositorio. Al hacer composer install, guardas el commit exacto de las dependencias de tu proyecto. Si una de estas librerías introduce un "backward compatibility break" puedes encontrarte en la situación de necesitar revertir las dependencias a un estado anterior, si no dispones del archivo composer.lock puede ser bastante difícil arreglarlo, sobretodo si no tienes mucha experiencia con composer.

Por otro lado no deberías de mantener dependencias en `dev-master` a no ser que sea completa y estrictamente indispensable (temporal). Las librerías de sonata tienen versiones etiquetadas, puedes encontrarlas en [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/sonata-project/user-bundle#3.6.0). Un buen punto de partida son las etiquetadas con 3, por ejemplo:

```
"sonata-project/user-bundle" : "^3"
```

Esta misma semana salió [symfony3.4](https://symfony.com/blog/symfony-3-4-0-released) y [symfony4](https://symfony.com/blog/symfony-4-0-0-released) así que es posible que introduzcan cambios en esa rama para arreglar incompatibilidades con la última versión.